# Serialização LocalDateTime

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Estou tentando serializar um objeto que possui uma data com a classe LocalDateTime utilizando o Spring Boot, mas o seguinte erro:

```
2016-10-09 18:28:26.218 WARN 17395 --- [ XNIO-2 task-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Text '2016-10-09T13:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: br.com.wt.agendadoador.modelo.Agenda["date"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2016-10-09T13:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: br.com.wt.agendadoador.modelo.Agenda["date"])
```

Fiz algumas pesquisas mas não consegui encontrar o motivo...

Trecho da classe:

```
@Entity
public class Agenda {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="doador_id")
@JsonProperty
private Doador doador;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StatusAgenda statusAgenda;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="laboratorio_id")
@JsonProperty
private Laboratorio laboratorio;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Minha configuração no application.properties e Jackson-datetype-jrs310:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS =false
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Por fim o Controller
`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "agenda")
public class AgendaController {

@Autowired
private AgendaRepository agendaRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
public ResponseEntity<Void> add(@Valid @RequestBody Agenda agenda) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    try {
        agenda.setStatusAgenda(StatusAgenda.EMABERTO);
        agendaRepository.save(agenda);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (RuntimeErrorException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }

}`
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que você deveria botar a annotation `@JsonDeserialize` em cima do campo `date` da sua classe `Agenda` para utilizar esse deserializer apenas para este campo. Se você quiser registrar o deserializer globalmente para que todo campo do tipo `LocalDateTime` utilize este deserializer, então você deve fazer assim:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Item.class, new ItemDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Como você deve estar utilizando spring-boot, você tem que configurar o modulo no mapper já criado pela auto-configuração, eu costuma fazer dessa forma:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private void registerSerializersDeserializers(List<ObjectMapper> objectMappers) {
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());

        objectMappers.forEach(objectMapper -> objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule));
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Após aplicar a configuração o Warn não mostra mais, mas agora o objeto vem nulo. Tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Assim de cara eu arrisco dizer que pode ser o formato da sua data. Eu removeria as annotations de formato em cima do atributo e passaria no json na formatação padrão que é iso-8601.

Comment: Realmente a data esta vindo errada por isso não estava serializando. Obrigado pela força.